# How to alert selected option text with JavaScript using onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm having trouble alerting option's innerHTML when I use onchange event, so far I have came up to this solution which works as intended but I think there's an easier way of doing it by not using *if*, *else if* and *else* statements. Actual question is how do I get option text? I figured out how to get value but I still have trouble getting the text which I got value of.
TLDR
How do I alert selected option? i.e. `window.alert('You have selected ' + geometricShape);`

```
 <form>
        <label id="izborNatpis" for="izbor">Geometrijski lik:</label>

        <select onchange="izborLik()" id="izbor">
<option value="1">Pravokutnik</option>
<option value="2">Kružnica</option>
<option value="3">Pravokutni trokut</option>
</select>

        <label id="natpis1" for="polje1">A:</label>
        <input id="polje1" type="number">
        <label id="natpis2" for="polje2">B:</label>
        <input id="polje2" type="number">
        <label id="natpis3" for="polje3">C:</label>
        <input id="polje3" type="number">
        <button type="button">Izračunaj</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function izborLik() {
            let lik = document.getElementById('izbor').value;
            if (lik == 1) {
                window.alert("Odabrani geometrijski lik je Pravokutnik");
            } else if (lik == 2) {
                window.alert("Odabrani geometrijski lik je Kružnica");
            } else {
                window.alert("Odabrani geometrijski lik je Pravokutni trokut");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a several ways to achieve this. One of them:

```
  function izborLik() {

    // Find select element
    const selectEl = document.querySelector('#izbor');

    // Get selected value
    const selectedValue = selectEl.value;
    
    // Find selected option according to a selected value and get its inner text
    const innerText = selectEl.querySelector(`option[value='${selectedValue}']`).innerText;

    window.alert(`Odabrani geometrijski lik je ${innerText}`);
    
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the `text` value of the selected Option you can use the `selectedIndex` property of the `option` to access that option's text value as below.

```js
document.querySelector('#izbor').addEventListener('change',function(e){
  alert( `Odabrani geometrijski lik je ${this.options[ this.options.selectedIndex ].text}` );
});
```

```html
<select id="izbor">
  <option value="1">Pravokutnik</option>
  <option value="2">Kružnica</option>
  <option value="3">Pravokutni trokut</option>
</select>
```

To summarise the format would be:

```
N.options[ N.options.selectedIndex ].text
```

Where `N` is a reference to the parent `SELECT` element. You can apply `dataset` attributes to an `option` that remain unseen by the casual user but which might be called upon with Javascript if required. To extend the previous brief example if every `option` element had a dataset attribute called `womble` you could easily access that dataset value like so:

```
N.options[ n.options.selectedIndex ].dataset.womble
```

To simply access the `value` of the `option` then `this.value` is sufficient ( in this context ) and if the option is of the form `<option>Banana` then again `this.value` should suffice as the text value is used as the value.

Answer (score 1):

This is also way to go.

```
 function izborLik()
    {
    let tmp=document.getElementById("izbor");
    let x=tmp.value;
    let lik="";
    if (x==1) lik="Pravokutnik";
    else if (x==2) lik="Kružnica";
    else if (x==3) lik="Pravokutni trokut";
    window.alert("Odabrani geometrijski lik: \n\t"+lik);
    }
```